# Usinge @Input to increment count of parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing a simple exercise to demonstrate Child/Parent interaction of variables in Angular. I have looked for solutions online but mostly have been suggesting Observables, Services, and Event Emitters. These however don't help with the scope of what I'm doing and I want to achieve a simple increment of a child component. Here's what I have:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "counter",
  template: `
    <h2>
      <p>{{ count }}</p>
      <counter-button></counter-button>
    </h2>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .counter-button {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #585858;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class CounterComponent {
  count: number = 42;
}

@Component({
  selector: "counter-button",
  template: `
    <button (click)="increment()">
      Click
    </button>
  `
})
export class CounterButtonComponent {
  @Input() count: number;

  constructor() {}

  increment() {
    this.count++;
  }
}
```

My task here is to have `CounterButtonComponent` increment the value count in `CounterComponent` after invoking the function `increment()` via a button click. I tried passing on the component via constructor but the value was not being assigned back to the main count. How can I use @Input to send the count to the child component and have it increment the parent count? Without using services, emitters, observables.. etc..

Thank you

Comment: Why without using emitters? The simplest way is to use an `EventEmitter<number>` as `@Output`,  which will emit the value each time when you increment the number, and the parent need to listen for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an eventlistener on the button in the counter component.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "counter",
  template: `
    <h2>
      <p>{{ count }}</p>
      <counter-button></counter-button>
    </h2>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      .counter-button {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        color: #585858;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {
  count: number = 42;
  ngOnInit() {
  document
  .querySelector("#increment")
  .addEventListener("click", () => this.increment());
  }
  increment() {
    this.count++;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: "counter-button",
  template: `
    <button id="increment">
      Click
    </button>
  `
})
export class CounterButtonComponent {

  constructor() {}
}
```

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bja8fe?) where everything should work as you want.

Comment: Your solution works 100% but I'm wondering for the sake of learning is this only achievable with Event emitters? Like what would possibly be the best solution with the least number of imports needed regarding Child/Parent interaction?

No services, no observables, no emitters, and so on.. just simple data binding / decorators

Comment: @Mustafa I've updated my solution. No event emitter nor Input is used. I hope that's what you are looking for. I've also updated to the stackblitz example

Comment: I prefer the older solution - Its just my question was with best Angular practices would you only use Event Emitters? Can it only be achieved with @Input decorators only?

Comment: @Mustafa Yes. The best thing to use in your case is Event Emitters. But there are other solutions provided by angular to implement component interaction (like using a service). You can read more about them in the following link https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild

Answer (score 0):

@Mustafa, if you pass a number, only pass the value. This is the reason you need use eventEmitter. You can also pass an object. Then, any change in one property of the object was reflected in the parent.

child:

```
@Input() countObj: any;

increment(){
   this.countObj.counter++;  
}
```

parent

```
   countObj={counter:0}

   <child [countObj]="countObj"></child>
   {{countObj.counter}}
```